# Можно ли узнать кто прячется за ServiceHost?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, процесс

При работе с пакетом офиса через Microsoft.Office.Interop в процессах создается офисные приложения.

Например, работая с Word создастся процесс Word'a, а сам интерфейс будет невидимым.

Так вот, можно ли понять, что этот Word связан с моей программой, а не сам пользователь его запустил, пока программа выполняется?

Пробовал родительский PID получать, так вот он относится к ServiceHost=> я не могу сравнить его с PID своей программы, что бы удостоверится, что я породил данный процесс.

Comment: Попробуйте ProcessExplorer от Sysinternals. Может он прояснит ситуацию.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего - выбрать сервисы через WMI (System.Management.dll) и отфильтровать по процессу, примерно так:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
```

---

```
ManagementObjectSearcher windowsServicesSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2", "select * from Win32_Service");
ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = windowsServicesSearcher.Get();

var services = objectCollection
    .Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .Select(mo => new
    {
        Name = mo.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString(),
        ProcessID = mo.Properties["ProcessId"].Value.ToString()
    })
    .Where(s => s.ProcessID != "0")
    .ToList();

services
    .GroupBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.ProcessID), g => g.Name)
    .Where(g => Process.GetProcessById(g.Key).ProcessName.Contains("svchost"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine($"{g.Key}: \t {String.Join(",", g)}"));
```

Способ сделать то же самое без кода и без сторонних утилит:

В Task Manager в контекстном меню на списке процессов выбрать Go to service(s).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Task Manager переключится на список сервисов, все сервисы внутри процесса будут выделены в списке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Зная PID, можно [получить список окон](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net) данного процесса. Зная handle окна, ему можно отправлять сообщения, а значит узнать его класс, заголовок, все атрибуты, список дочерних окон и.т.д. (в [примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584672/5485944) как раз идет получение заголовка). В общем, с чужим окном через handle можно делать практически все то, что и с собственным.

У интерактивных программ с GUI, очевидно, окон будет очень много. Как минимум одно из них является главным окном приложения, его можно идентифицировать по заголовку, атрибутам и набору дочерних окон.

У процессов, подключенных к ServiceHost, окон, скорее всего, не будет вообще. Или будут какие-то служебные окна, но все они будут скрытые (проверяется это [просто](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) и их набор будет довольно постоянным, так как пользователь не взаимодействует с GUI.